# Is ok to ask what type of modules can help you accomplish a feature?

Tags: support, questions

I was reading the FAQ but it does not say if I can ask or no about what modules can be useful to implement a feature or behaviour.

I love this site because I spent days doing research about how to implement some behaviour in Drupal. Then, I asked what modules I should use or in what way I could accomplished that. I have two valuable answers that gave me the right track.

However, now that I am more familiar with drupal.stackexchange and I more concern to follow the rules. I wonder if my question was valid in first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your question describes exactly what features you are looking for, and the description is not too vague, the question is acceptable. If then you also say which modules you already tried, and for which reason they didn't suit your needs, that is even better.
The only limit the FAQ puts is not asking which module should be used to implement a feature, where instead of describing the feature, the OP shows a screenshot, or gives the URL of a site where the feature has been seen. ("Implementing a functionality, or a layout, seen in a site for which only a screenshot, or the site URL is provided.")

As for previous search, generally speaking that is always welcome on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Thanks...I was concern about his  :)